# NServiceBus - Saga Auditing - no handlers found exception

Tags: nservicebus, msmq, messaging, nservicebus5

We are using NServiceBus 5.2.14 hosted inside .Net 4.6.1 windows services. 
We have added NServiceBus auditing to our services via the AuditConfig:

```
<AuditConfig QueueName="AuditService"  />
```

When we turned on Auditing for the windows service containing our Sagas, we noticed some new subscriptions added to our subscriptions Sql table. Like these:

```
SubscriberEndpoint                             MessageType
ServiceThatIsPublishingEventTypeA@MyMachine    MyAssembly.MessageTypeA,1.0.147.0
AuditService@MyMachine                         MyAssembly.MessageTypeA,1.0.147.0
```

It seems that after enabling auditing on the Saga service, the service that is publishing an event (that the saga is subscribing to), now gets a recursive subscription to itself.

When a message is processed, a copy is successfully pushed to the audit queue.

However, the problem I am having is that I also get a copy of the message pushed into the *ServiceThatIsPublishingEventTypeA.Error* queue and an exception raised in my log.

The exception is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No handlers could be found for message  type: MyAssembly.MessageTypeA
 at NServiceBus.LoadHandlersBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in  C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\LoadHandlersBehavior.cs:line 29
at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 107
at   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4_0.&lt;InvokeNext&gt;b__0() in  C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line 94
```

This makes sense as there are no handlers for *MyAssembly.MessageTypeA* event within *ServiceThatIsPublishingEventTypeA* service (it just publishes these events), yet the auditing has added this subscription.

**So my question is:** Is that recursive subscription correct? what is the correct way to audit the traffic through a saga (and avoid the errors being raised)?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is your AuditService an NServiceBus endpoint? If it is how is it configured? I mean what messages does it process?

Comment: Yes the AuditService is an NSB endpoint.  It processes all of the messages running through our various services - It has a handler <IMyMessage> which is on all of our messages.

Comment: it logs these messages in our db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the endpoint is auto subscribing to the events it finds in assembly scanning, can you try and [disable auto subscribe](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/publish-subscribe/controlling-what-is-subscribed)?

== EDIT

After [looking at the code on github](https://github.com/seantarogers/AuditingIssue/pull/1) i created a pull request with a version that works, the main issue was that the audit component was processing subscription messages it received via the audit channel...

I also cleaned up some minor redundant code

Comment: Hi Sean, sorry about the delay in replying. The disable auto subscribe did not fix the issue.  I have created a repo here: https://github.com/seantarogers/AuditingIssue if you get a chance to look at it.  Thanks

Comment: I'll take a look and get back to you

Comment: Updated my answer, if you want to have a meeting offline email me sean.farmar at particular.net

HTH